# Get worksheet_index with google-drive-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working with [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) and trying to get a the worksheet_index when Looping through them:

```
# Login
@session = GoogleDrive.login("email", "password")

# Get Specific Spreadsheet
@spreadsheets = @session.spreadsheet_by_key("spreadsheet_key")
```

So now i have access to my Spreadsheet on Google Drive and can loop through the Worksheets:

```
<% @spreadsheets.worksheets.each do |c| %>
  <% c.title %>
<% end %>
```

All fine till now. My Problem is the actual `Export` of the document.

[class GoogleDrive::Spreadsheet](http://gimite.net/doc/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/Spreadsheet.html#method-i-export_as_file)

```
export_as_file(local_path, format = nil, worksheet_index = nil)
# Exports the spreadsheet in format as a local file.
```

so to identify a specific worksheet I need that `worksheet_index` so i can export the right one.

And here I'm stuck, i searched for hours now but cant seem to find **HOW** i can get that `worksheet_index`. Is there another way ? What am I missing?

**Edit**

I need to be able to pull a specific Worksheet in my Spreadsheet. (Every Worksheet has a 'google given' index_key)

[Github Repo of export_method](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/lib/google_drive/spreadsheet.rb#L140)

[google-drive-ruby gem](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby)

[Google Drive API Docs](http://gimite.net/doc/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/Spreadsheet.html)

Comment: `@spreadsheets.worksheets.each_with_index do |c,worksheet_index|` ?

Comment: That doesn't work actually, as Worksheets have their own index_key, so generating that based on a list doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the gid values.
Click in your google spreadsheet on one of the worsheettabs and in the url you'll see something like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AroM_DeBu-WAdFBEeVo2RlZ4ejhfdDetc&usp=drive_web#gid=3

Then in your script use this gid valua as your worksheet_index

```
@spreadsheets.export_as_file("c:\\test_sp3.xls", "xls", 3)
```

My experience is that it doesn't matter which gid you use als long as it is a valid one, the resulting xls (in this case) contains all the worksheets from your spreadsheet.

You can also leave the third parameter.

```
@spreadsheets.export_as_file("c:\\test_sp3.xls", "xls")
```

Comment: My problem is that i have to look that up in my App. for 100's of documents.. Actually @gaurav's method worked fine !

Comment: that is a coincidence i'm afraid, with my example it doesn't work

Comment: Not a coincidence IM AFRAID.. as i saw just now, that passes the index number based on the list i'm generating, not the index number from the  actual Worksheet :(

Comment: i think that if you deleted a sheet before in that spreadsheet the index is no longer the same as the order of the sheet

Comment: Oh... I didn't knew that.. So what's the best approach to this now?? I couldn't find any other way to export_to_file without an Index..

Comment: i would put it into a begin,rescue block and start with gid=0 and add untill a valid gid is used, in most cases the value of 0 will be good, didn't find a way to get the gid from a spreadsheet or worksheet until now

Comment: I just created a worksheet which has an id of '1033040152'... and the next one has '26896'.. I don't think they are generating the gid based on the Worksheets on a given Spreadsheet.

Comment: I just tried without the third parameter (gid) and it works also !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56711/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-peter).

Comment: I think my explanation didn't give you enough information. The problem is that i NEED that index_key (else i just pull the first worksheet in my Spreadsheet). That index_key (third parameter) specifies which worksheet to pull, and MY problem is how to get that index_key